# Get videos using play-list

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to write a code that retrieves all the videos related to a specific play list.
what the query should I use?
for example : I have used the

"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=3"
query to get all the videos related by the user.

The "username" field  takes the value from edit text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search this link : 
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#authorsp

And you can use query like you wrote : `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=json`

For spesicif playlist first of all, research this link which is about getting playlist.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists

You can get playlist in xml format  : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thenewboston/playlists?v=2

if you want it in json append &alt=json to query. This link will give you playlists.

And use URL like this getting playlist's items  :https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2

For getting playlist item's in Json data, you must get the this node :

```
    "content": {

        "type": "application/atom+xml;type=feed",
        "src": "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL6gx4Cwl9DGCS7sMM-19z9_ud7F2SINJq?v=2
},
```

this node is from thenewboston's playlist data.
You can find more information about Youtube API and playlist check this link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists and Retrieving a single playlist title.

Comment: @:mertaydin: If I can use the query I have wrote what to put in the "username" field in order to get the play-list I want?

Comment: You must wrote the username field Youtube username. For example, getting thenewboston account's videos (link is http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston) you must use query like this : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=thenewboston&v=2&alt=json

Comment: OK. but what if thenwboston has many videos and I want only a specific play-list related to him?

Comment: Ok. I'm updating my answer.